# Group by, count and stream individual results from mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In mongodb, having a collection with `sessionId`s and `label`s, I would like to group by the sessionId where label equals 'view_item' and accomplish:

- Get the count of sessionId groups.
- Be able to stream each sessionId to the consumer (assuming I have limited memory resources and a large number individual `sessionId`s)

**Assume following documents in a collection:**

```
{ "label" : "view_item", "sessionId" : "01e5dnnpsczgfq58rmp0cjtjm0" }
{ "label" : "view_category", "sessionId" : "01e5dnnpsczgfq58rmp0cjtjm0" }
{ "label" : "view_item", "sessionId" : "01e5dnnpsczgfq58rmp0cjtjm0" }
{ "label" : "view_item", "sessionId" : "01e5g7vzx5dh0mv8m6g1zbdrnj" }
{ "label" : "view_item", "sessionId" : "01e5g7vzx5dh0mv8m6g1zbdrnj" }
{ "label" : "view_category", "sessionId" : "01e5g7vzx5dh0mv8m6g1zbdrnj" }
{ "label" : "view_item", "sessionId" : "01e5g7vzx5dh0mv8m6g1zbdrnj" }
```

**The expected result would be something like this:**

Get `results` somehow and...

```
result.count() // 2 (or some other way of getting the count)
await result.next() // { sessionId: '01e5dnnpsczgfq58rmp0cjtjm0' }
await result.next() // { sessionId: '01e5g7vzx5dh0mv8m6g1zbdrnj' }
await result.next() // null
```

I've been fiddling with the aggregation framework and manage to group and count. In theory I could do two queries to first get count and then the groups, but in a frequent write scenario I'm worried that doing two separate queries could lead to inconsistencies, especially since I haven't figured out how to  include any start / end ids in the result from the count query, which could be used to confine the results from the groups query.

**What I have so far is:**

```
const result = collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { label: 'view_item' } },
  { $group : { _id: { sessionId: '$sessionId' } } },
]);

await result.next() // { _id: { sessionId: '01e5g7vzx5dh0mv8m6g1zbdrnj' } }
await result.next() // { _id: { sessionId: '01e5dnnpsczgfq58rmp0cjtjm0' } }
await result.next() // null
```

and

```
const result = collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { label: 'view_item' } },
  { $group : { _id: { sessionId: '$sessionId' } } },
  { $facet: { count: [{ $count: 'count' }] } }
]);

await result.next() // { count: [ { count: 2 } ] }
await result.next() // null
```

**Question**

How can the two queries above be combined to reliably get the count and a result with the grouped sessionId that can be streamed? (I assume any solution relying on `result.toArray().length` needs to load the whole result in memory, which is ruled out).

Is it possible to do in one single query or more likely to get the count and start / end ids in one query and then do a second query to get the groups confined by the start / end ids?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you requirements clearly, you need to gather all the sessions that have been assigned to each label in one array, and count that sessions

if so, we may use the $group to group the sessions assigned to each label, 
and $size to calculate that array length

we may do something like that

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {} // if you need the 'View_Item' labels only, than add it here
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$label", // make the _id of the results is the label
      sessionsIds: { // array of sessions
        $push: "$sessionId"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { // use the $project as $size is available only in the $project stage
      _id: 1,
      sessionsIds: 1,
      sessionsCount: {
        $size: "$sessionsIds"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

you could try that here in [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/63WyXe0EbVC)

> Update, If you need to get the number of unique sessions Ids, and no duplication in `sessionsIds` array, use `$addToSet` instead of `$push`

---

> **update 2**: If we need to group by the sessionId and count how many documents have this sessionId, we can do something like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {} // if you need the 'View_Item' labels only, than add it here
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$sessionId",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

this will return a result

```
[
  {
    "_id": "01e5dnnpsczgfq58rmp0cjtjm0",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": "01e5g7vzx5dh0mv8m6g1zbdrnj",
    "count": 4
  }
]
```

if you need to make the _id of the result be an object rather than ObjectId, we could do something like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {} // if you need the 'View_Item' labels only, than add it here
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        sessionId: "$sessionId"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

this will result in

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "sessionId": "01e5dnnpsczgfq58rmp0cjtjm0"
    },
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "sessionId": "01e5g7vzx5dh0mv8m6g1zbdrnj"
    },
    "count": 4
  }
]
```

you can try all of that here [Mongo_Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vZgzqKEF8N7)

Comment: Thanks! Elegant. The query result contains the data I need, but the crux is that I expect to have many sessionsIds and low memory resources, so I need to be able to stream the sessionId array using some async mechanism such as `await result.next()` I mentioned in the question.

Comment: so we need to group the documents by the sessionId not the label, and then count the number of sessionIds, right?

Comment: could you try that ... https://mongoplayground.net/p/iGiXYqm3fCQ, I will update my answer to have this too

Comment: @Claudijo, I have just updated my answer again, could you check it now? hope it will work as you needed :)

Comment: Thanks @Mohammed Yousry. Your initial answer using `$addToSet` resulted in the data structure I was looking for, however you get it in one single big array (assuming there are many sessionIds) and I need to stream the result as individual sessionIds without loading the whole array into memory.